# How to Detect a Streak of Certain Values in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a Python DataFrame, I want to detect the beginning and end position of  a block of `False` values in a row. If the block contains just one `False`, I would like to get that position.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, True, True,False,False,False,True,False,True],})
In[110]: df
Out[111]: 
       a
0   True
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
5  False
6   True
7  False
8   True
```

In this example, I would like to get the positions

```
`3`, `5`
```

and

```
`7`, `7`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
a = (df.a.cumsum()[~df.a]
         .reset_index()
         .groupby('a')['index']
         .agg(['first','last'])
         .values
         .tolist())
print(a)
[[3, 5], [7, 7]]
```

**Explanation**:

First get cumulative sum by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) - get for all `False` unique groups:

```
print (df.a.cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    4
8    5
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Filter only `False` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with invert boolean column:

```
print (df.a.cumsum()[~df.a])
3    3
4    3
5    3
7    4
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Create column from index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.a.cumsum()[~df.a].reset_index())
   index  a
0      3  3
1      4  3
2      5  3
3      7  4
```

For each group aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) functions [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
print (df.a.cumsum()[~df.a].reset_index().groupby('a')['index'].agg(['first','last']))
   first  last
a             
3      3     5
4      7     7
```

Last convert to nested `list`:

```
print (df.a.cumsum()[~df.a].reset_index().groupby('a')['index'].agg(['first','last']).values.tolist())
[[3, 5], [7, 7]]
```